# How to Push and Pull Variable in SESSION type Array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am willing to create a Shop Cart using simple PHP SESSION ARRAY. I tried to search different StackOverFlow problems, but none of those is giving me exact solution of my problem. Maybe I am doing any silly  mistake. However,

I am doing this:

```
<!-- SHOPPING CART -->
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['atc']))
{
    $item = $_REQUEST['atc'];
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $item);
    //$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;

     foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $val)
    { 
        echo $key . ">" . $val;
    }
}
?>
<!-- SHOPPING CART -->
```

I am receiving `$_REQUEST['ate']` (Integer Value/Product ID) when User is Clicking "ADD TO CART" Button on the same page. Then I am putting the value in $item, then I am declaring `$_SESSION['cart']` as Array. Then I have tried `array_push`, and even tried `$_SESSION['cart'][]` to Push Integer Value. But each time only the first element is updated, therefore `$_SESSION['cart'][0]` is storing the value, not `$_SESSION['cart'][1]` or the rest.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to call this file or how do you manage "when User is Clicking"?

Comment: No AJAX, just simple PHP.

Comment: <a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?atc=".$songs['song_id']."\" title=\"Click Here to Add this song to Cart\" class=\"buy\" target=\"\"><img src=\"images/cart.png\"></a>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you redefine `$_SESSION['cart']` every time as an empty array via `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` and then only push one element.

Try this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['atc']))
{
    $item = $_REQUEST['atc'];

    if (!isSet($_SESSION['cart']))
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $item);
    //$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;

     foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $val)
    { 
        echo $key . ">" . $val;
    }
}
```

Now only the first time a user wants to add an item, `$_SESSION['cart']` will be initiated as an empty an array. The second time (`$_SESSION['cart']` already is an array with one element), the second element will properly be pushed.

---

If you want the elements to be unique (as said in comments), you can use the elements id as key (and an array can only have unique keys).

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['atc']))
{
    $item = $_REQUEST['atc'];

    if (!isSet($_SESSION['cart']))
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

    if (!array_key_exists($item, $_SESSION['cart']))
        $_SESSION['cart'][$item] = 1;
    else
        $_SESSION['cart'][$item]++;

    foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $val)
    { 
        echo $key . ">" . $val;
    }
}
```

This will first check, if the item is already in the cart (`array_key_exists`), if not it will be added. If it is, it will increment the value, so you can keep track how often a specific item is in the cart (if you don't want that functionality, just lose the `else` statement)

Comment: You are welcome. If this (or devBinnooh's) answer helped you, please consider upvoting and/or marking an answer as accepted

Comment: alright sure, I will. Can you give me one  more solution? How can I add distinct element in an array. Therefore, the products are unique. So, if visitor adds multiple same item, only one Item-ID will be added to the Array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you override $_SESSION['cart'] every time you get an item. Try

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

    //array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $item);
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
```

Check first that the session is not already exist, then add items.

[Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Can you give me about one more solution? How can I add distinct element in an array. Therefore, the products are unique. So, if visitor adds multiple same item, only one Item-ID will be added to the Array.